# Font-Awesome Icons are not centering on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, center, font-awesome

I have a div that is a page on my site, and I am trying to center these font-awesome icons on it. But for some reason they wont center. I have searched for a solution but none have worked so far.

Click the "about" button to see what I am talking about.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#fadeContent').click(function(){
    var bodyContent = $('#bodyContent')
    bodyContent.fadeIn(400);
    bodyContent.click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(400);
    })
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color:black;
}

#bodyContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#454545;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fa-times{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-github,
.fa-steam {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.fa-times:hover{
    color: #e84d4d;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#projects {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 71%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#home:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.about:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#projects:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contact:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>  
<body>
    
    <button id="home">Home</button>
    <button id="fadeContent" class="about">About</button>
    <button id="projects">Projects</button>
    <button id="contact">Contact</button>
    
      <div id="bodyContent">
          <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#bodyContent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('#fadeContent').click(function() {
    var bodyContent = $('#bodyContent')
    bodyContent.fadeIn(400);
    bodyContent.click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(400);
    })
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
}

#bodyContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #454545;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-times {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-github,
.fa-steam {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 3px solid white;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.fa-times:hover {
  color: #e84d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#home {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 37%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#projects {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 54%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#contact {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 71%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#home:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.about:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#projects:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#contact:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Home</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <button id="home">Home</button>
  <button id="fadeContent" class="about">About</button>
  <button id="projects">Projects</button>
  <button id="contact">Contact</button>

  <div id="bodyContent">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center` to `#bodyContent` in CSS.

Comment: To center inline elements you'll want to use `text-align: center` on the parent div, that's why it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a content wrapper inside that `#bodyContent` div, you can solve it easily with flexbox.

Here is the modified code, I reduced the margin on icons as well, wrapped them inside a div (with a height fitting the container), with items aligned to center, and content justified to center. This will render the icons in the absolute middle of the `#bodyContent`.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#fadeContent').click(function() {
    var bodyContent = $('#bodyContent')
    bodyContent.fadeIn(400);
    bodyContent.click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(400);
    })
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
}

#bodyContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #454545;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fa-times {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-github,
.fa-steam {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 3px solid white;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.fa-times:hover {
  color: #e84d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#home {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 37%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#projects {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 54%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#contact {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 71%;
  height: 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#home:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.about:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#projects:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#contact:hover {
  color: #1dd2e2;
  border: 3px solid #18bdef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.bodyContent-inside {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Home</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <button id="home">Home</button>
  <button id="fadeContent" class="about">About</button>
  <button id="projects">Projects</button>
  <button id="contact">Contact</button>

  <div id="bodyContent">
    <div class="bodyContent-inside">
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cheers!